# Typescript's declare module with body and without

Tags: typescript, mdxjs

I've got a `.mdx` file.

Having the following in `mdx.d.ts`:

```
/// <reference types="@mdx-js/loader" />
import { ComponentType } from "react";

declare module '*.mdx' {
  const Component: ComponentType;
  export default Component;
}
```

Makes

```
import Comp from "./Comp.mdx";
```

throw "TS2307: Cannot find module './Comp.mdx' or its corresponding type declarations."

However having just the following works:

```
declare module '*.mdx';
```

Why is that?

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["**/*.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/// 
import { ComponentType } from "react";

Dont know why but remove the import sentence make it working. Change ComponentType to any.